# What do the numbers next to the names of player killed represent?

Tags: overwatch

Upon killing an enemy player, a notification pops up in the middle of the screen, e.g., "Killed PLAYERNAME ##" with a number. These numbers appear to be out of 100 and to contribute to being "on fire".

What are these numbers? The damage percentage that you contributed to the kill? If you headshot a 100 HP player who only has 1 HP left, would you get "1"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been digging around to try and answer this question.  From [what I've found](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/182930-overwatch/73781327), the number appears to be an percentage of the amount of damage you did to that person.

Some other sources saying its percentage based:

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ek16r/numbers_after_a_kill/)
- [Battle.net](http://eu.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/17612001483)

> If you headshot a 100 HP player who only has 1 HP left, would you get "1"?

Based off the sources I found, I would have to say yes since 1% of 100 would be 1.

Comment: It also shows you the amount of "Firepoints" got. So if you solo kill anyone, you get to be more on fire, unlike if you had just finished him off with 1HP.

Comment: Also, when you for example hit Roadhog his full 600HP (while Roadhog is getting healed), and someone finished him, you also get 100 points... Or, atleast that's what I think is the case.

Answer (score 2):

The number represent the amount of "Firepoints" you get with the kill (like Nutty said in the comments).

The amount of point you get is calculated from the perfentage of damage you made to the enemy.

Comment: Note that it takes 250 fire points for a character to become "on fire," and you only accumulate these fire points when the elimination occurs.  That means you need at least 3 eliminations with two and a half health pools worth of damage if you're playing a character with no other means of gaining fire points (like McCree or Junkrat).

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Fire also decays over time, so those kills need to be in rapid succession, while standing on an objective, or getting fire from some other source (blocking damage, for example)